# Robocopy will not copy files involving any external drives

Tags: windows-7, permissions, cmd.exe, robocopy

I am attempting to back up data onto some external hard drives as a part of my job, the data sets can be over 100GB in size with specific file structure so using robocopy is a must.

When I run this command where G:\ is an external hard drive or even usb stick and [source] is an internal drive,

```
robocopy [source] G:\ /E
```

I get the error

```
G:\System Volume Information\2018\01/11 15:36:59 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Changing file attributes G:/
Access is denied
Waiting 30 seconds...
```

This error also occurs when copying from an external drive to a different external drive.

I have a feeling this has to do with setting permissions, but I am not sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to copy the `\System Volume Information` folder?  Generally you can exclude that.  It doesn't directly have any of you data.  Also, if the destination is also an NTFS volume it will already have a `\System Volume Information` folder that it might not be a good idea to over-write.

Also, you might want to include the `/b` (backup) , and/or `/zb` (backup+restarable) options when using robocopy for backups.  Assuming you have administrator privileges on the system this will allow you to bypass a lot of the standard access controls on a system.

One other suggestion.  If you really need to make a copy of the entire filesystem/volume you might want to look at using something like [disk2vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd) instead of robocopy.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `\System Volume Information` folder in the source, but the destination is NTFS so it definitely will have one.  Is there a way to except this particular folder from the robocopy command? <br/> Also just to be clear, I'm not copying filesystems or volumes, but just a series of folders containing GIS data.

Comment: Full CLI option list is here.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx.  The exclude would probably be like `/xd '\System Volume Information'` or something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even after adding `/xd '\System Volume Information'` I get the same error.

Comment: You appear to be copying the root of one to the source to the root of the destination.  Do you have to do that? With the error I have to assume 'System Volume Information' does exist on the source otherwise I cant see Robocopy overwriting it

Comment: Try this syntax:  -x!"System Volume Information"  .. (note the absence of a backslash)